# How do you float two divs next to each other using %-defined widths but px-defined padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float an image to the left of a block of text and maintain a slight gap between the two, however I don't want the text to snake underneath the image. This is what I want:

```
------- ------------
| pic | |   text   |
------- |          |
        |          |
        |          |
        ------------
```

This would be easy if the widths and sizes of all the elements were px-defined, but they are % defined:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="theimage"><img src=img.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thetext">blah blah</div>
</div>

#container {width: 95%; overflow: auto}
.theimage {float: left; width: 20%}
.theimage img {width: 100%}
.thetext {float: left; width: 80%}
```

This above works fine. However, if I then add `padding-right: 10px` to `theimage` to create a gap between the image and the text, `thetext` drops beneath `theimage` instead of floating next to it.

Any help with getting a gap in between `theimage` and `thetext`?

Comment: Not sure how to fins the duplicates, but this question has been done to death

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the property `box-sizing: border-box`. Under the normal `content-box` model, padding of an element is not included in the height calculation, so you are adding 10px to the 20% of the image, therefore the sum of the image and the text will be 20% + 10px + 100%, which of course exceeds the parent width.

In fact, [Paul Irish recommends using](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) the CSS rule, `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`, because of how much headache it will save you from calculating dimensions, and yet having insignificant impact on browser performance and page rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` on the element that you add padding to.  This causes the padding to become part of its width calculation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/jqjqd/1/

---

Alternative solution:

Instead of using `float: left` use `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` on the container.  This will force the elements to stay on a single line.

You also need to set `white-space: normal` and `vertical-align: top` on the individual elements so they can grow with content and stay aligned to the top.  All together:

```
#container {
    width: 95%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.theimage {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}   
.thetext {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This causes a horizontal scrollbar on `#container` (as well it should because the padding causes the total width of its contents to exceed 100%).

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/jqjqd/